# Devops Pipeline project with Prebuild events

Tags: wpf, build, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

Hi i am really struggling to set up a pipeline on a project that has prebuild events.

The Solution itself builds all 21 projects nicely locally.

The prebuild event looks like this:

```
"$(SolutionDir)Removerowguids\bin\Debug\Removerowguids.exe" $(SolutionDir)Brouwen3.Business\Domains\Store\DcBrouwen.edmx
"$(SolutionDir)Removerowguids\bin\Debug\Removerowguids.exe" $(SolutionDir)Brouwen3.Business\Domains\Store\DcPCD.edmx
```

it removes some data from existing edmx's.

When i run my pipeline everything goes pretty well except the VS Build step.

This is the error it generates:

```
Error MSB3073: The command ""D:\a\1\s\Removerowguids\bin\Debug\Removerowguids.exe" D:\a\1\s\Mits.Business\Store\MesBrouwen.edmx" exited with code 3.
```

```
Error MSB3073: The command ""D:\a\1\s\Removerowguids\bin\Debug\Removerowguids.exe" D:\a\1\s\Brouwen3.Business\Domains\Store\DcBrouwen.edmx
```

The pipeline itself is pretty basic it tried MSBuild and VSBuild steps.

It would be nice if some could point out what is wrong here.

[image]

Comment: Code 3 is a path error. Check the path to your stuff on d and any component you're using in the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSB3073 just means something is wrong with the command, the last part `exited with code 3` of the error points to the path error which is listed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx) as:

> ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND 3 (0x3) The system cannot find the path
> specified.

`\bin\Debug` folder is generated after build, it does not exist during pre-build, you can try to place the .exe directly in Solution folder,for example: `"$(SolutionDir)Removerowguids.exe"` .